# Python3 converting byte to int

Tags: python-3.x, integer, byte

How to convert bytes to int in Python3

```
get_disk = b'8559555\\n'
current_disk = int(get_disk)
```

error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'8559555\\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get_disk = b'8559555\\n'
current_disk = int.from_bytes(get_disk, "big")
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)